# contains fails with ArrayList

Tags: java, contains

the following is part of a big library i write so i only show a small piece of code. If more is required, let me know.

I'm making a tool where i can select anchors of a bezier.
The strange thing is, i select one anchor for example.
Then i can hold shift for a toggle selection, where unselected anchors get selected and selected ones get unselected.
I select the same anchor.
Then in the first line of code it check if it was in the ArrayList lastAnchorSelection.
It was part but for some reason it continues.
Then it reports the size of the last selection, which is 1.
Then i get the object out of the arrayList and test it against v, it print out true.

So how can the first line result in false where the 4th line results in true?

```
if (lastAnchorSelection.contains(v) == false) {
  System.out.println("lastAnchorSelection.size(): "+lastAnchorSelection.size());
  CVector test = lastAnchorSelection.get(0);
  System.out.println(test == v);
  System.out.println("C");
```

Comment: what is the class of `v`? are you overriding `equals()`?

Comment: Post the `equals()` method of `CVector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collection.contains` is specified in terms of the `equals()` method.  Implementations of `equals()` are supposed to follow a number of rules (see the Object class javadoc), the first of which is

- It is reflexive: for any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` should return `true`.

but it looks like the class of `v` has a non-compliant `equals()` implementation that breaks this rule.

Either that or it's a threading issue, and some other thread is adding `v` to the list in between the `contains()` test and the `get(0)`.

Comment: damn your good. my v was a vector class that i basiscly copied and pased a lot of months ago with my own changes. I wasn't aware that it has it's own equals method.
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First line uses `equals()` to compare, the second one compares references.

Answer (score 0):

From [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

In your case, this would be `v.equals(test)`. When this returns false, `contains(v)` returns false as well.

Line 4 compares `v == test`, which is a different comparison than `v.equals(test)`.

`v == test` compares the references of `v` and `test`. When `v` and `test` reference the same object, this returns true. Whereas `v.equals(test)` calls the method `equals`, which might return anything (even false) depending on its implementation.

Comment: I tested and System.out.println(lastAnchorSelection.contains(v)); returns false indeed.
But i still don't get how line 4 can return true.